# Find most frequent element in a list in lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I've been searching for a while for a function that does this in (Common) Lisp. Does one already exist, or do I need to code it on my own? To be more specific, I'm looking for a function that if I fed it in something like '(1 2 4 1), it would return 1?

Comment: A very good reference to all the Common Lisp specification is the Hyperspec (http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/index.htm). You can see all the functions available in a specification conforming implementation.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to make it yourself. You'll need to keep the count for all the elements, then do a scan through the hash to find which one has the highest frequency.

Of course it could be that more than one has the highest frequency, what then?